# Why isn't my contact form using PHPMailer working?

Tags: php

I made a contact form to send information to my email, and whenever I submit the form, I get redirected to my php file (mywebsite.com/contact.php) and am shown a Internal Server Error (the 500 kind). What did I do wrong? Could it be because I have my html and php code in different files? I included my contact form as well just in case it is relevant.

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$message=
'Full Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br/>
Comments:    '.$_POST['comments'].'<br/>
Email:       '.$_POST['email'].'
';

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'aroncea@yahoo.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'letmejusteditthisout';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

$mail->addAddress('aroncea@yahoo.com');     // Add a recipient
$result = $mail->Send();
$message = $result ? 'Successfully sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';
unset($mail);

$mail->Subject = "New Form Submission";
$mail->MsgHTML($message);


?>
```

```html
<!-- Container (Contact Section) -->
<form action="newcontact.php" method="POST"  name='contactform' id='contactform' enctype="text/plain">
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p>Contact us and we'll get back to you within 24 hours. </p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Burlington, ON</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> 289-230-4510</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> aroncea@yahoo.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment (not required)" rows="3"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's in your web servers error log? It doesn't look like your closing your 'if' statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` in your PHP-File. (You open a `{` after the `if`-statement but never close it.)

With 500 Errors, it usually helps to check the servers error-log.

Answer (score 0):

assign your message and Subject before `$mail->Send();` and close `}`.
try this code.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$message=
'Full Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br/>
Comments:    '.$_POST['comments'].'<br/>
Email:       '.$_POST['email'].'
';

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'aroncea@yahoo.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'letmejusteditthisout';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

$mail->addAddress('aroncea@yahoo.com');     // Add a recipient

$mail->Subject = "New Form Submission";
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$result = $mail->Send();
$message = $result ? 'Successfully sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';
unset($mail);
}
```

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did what you said and now my form simply points to mywebsite.com/newcontact.php (that's the URL it's at) which turns out to be a completely blank page- not even the "Successfully sent" or "Sending Failed" is shown. Is there a site I can go to that checks to see if the PHP code is right? Where can I go for some troubleshooting?